# Comma Separated List of all columns in the Database (Tablename | Column_names...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, while-loop

In SQL Server, I would like see Table_Name and all the Columns associated with that Table_Name in a database. So the Output should look like this:

```
      TABLE_NAME     COLUMN_NAME 

   1. Employee       Employee-id, Lastname, Firstname, Title...........
   2. Orders         Orderid, Order-date, shipped-date, delivery-date.......
   3. Products       Product-id, Product-name, supplier-id, category-id.....
   4. Suppliers      Supplier-id, Company-name, contact-name.......
   5. ............................................................
   6. ...................................................
      (So on....)
```

Is it possible to get the above results with WHILE LOOP or any other way? If YES, could you post the code.

Also, I tried to do this problem using a Temp Table:

```
 create table #hello
 (table_name1 Varchar(max))
  insert into #hello(table_name1)
  select table_name from information_schema.columns 
 GO

 create table #hello2
 (table_name2 varchar(max),column_name2 varchar(max))
  insert into #hello2(table_name2 ,column_name2)
  select table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns 
 GO

 select  a.table_name1,b.column_name from #hello a inner join
   information_schema.columns b
 on a.table_name1=b.table_name COLLATE Latin1_general_CI_AS
 order by table_name 
 GO
```

I was successful in listing the columns Vertically but i couldn't get the comma separated list of columns.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I don't see why not. If they give an interesting problem, and you can answer with a "This is how you do this: <Code Snippet>" then why wouldn't you? I know it helps me learn how to do something to see relevant examples to my problem domain.

Not all users may want to build a query for another user, but I don't know why you'd try to speak for the community and say "We don't do this." I personally like helping people by providing queries for the problem they're working on. (Sorry for the long paragraph, I don't know how to enter newlines...)

Comment: @Jeremy Pridemore, why should I try to help someone who expects me to do the work he is paid to do? Someone should show that they at least tried or be asking what they need to know to start trying not asking directly for completed code for someone else to write.

Comment: I thought i posted my code with the question but i didn't. I tried doing this problem with Temp Tables and i posted my unsuccessful code above below the question. Thanks for all your comments and support.

Answer (score 34):

```
Select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
        From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
        Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
            And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
        Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
        For Xml Path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
```

As mentioned in comments, the above will include views. If you want to exclude views you can do the following:

```
Select T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
        From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
        Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
            And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
        Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
        For Xml Path('')
        ), 1, 2, '') As Columns
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
    Left Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS As V
        On V.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
            And V.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
Where V.TABLE_NAME Is Null
```

Comment: +1 That was fast. You should be aware that your query also returns views, not only tables.

Comment: @Lamak - Yes, yes. They can easily be excluded of course. Have posted that addition.

Comment: Oops,... Where T.TABLE_NAME Is Null

Comment: @Nimrod - Corrected almost as soon as I wrote it.

Comment: Thank Thomas. I tried doing this problem using Temp tables but was unsuccessful. I posted my code below my question.

Comment: @CricMan - I guess I'm missing something. The query I provided will give you exactly what you asked: a column with the table name (another for schema, but you can exclude that if they are all dbo) and another column with a comma-delimited list of column names in that table.

Comment: @CricMan - I.e., there is no need for temp tables. You can get the results you want in a single query.

Comment: @Thomas - I think the OP was just explaining their previous efforts (a bit stung by HLGEM's and OMG's remarks!)

Comment: @Thomas & Martin: The code works Great. Its just that i was trying a different way. Thanks for helping this naive Developer !

Comment: To filter tables/views, just add `TABLE_TYPE` into select list. 
Or use one of these where conditions: `WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW'` or `WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'`

Answer (score 8):

```
select name as TABLE_NAME,
       STUFF(COLUMN_NAME, 1, 1, '') AS COLUMN_NAME
from sys.tables t
CROSS APPLY 
( 
        SELECT 
            ',' + name AS [text()] 
        FROM 
            sys.columns c
        WHERE 
            c.object_id = t.object_id
        FOR XML PATH('') 
    ) o (COLUMN_NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried to do the problem with temp tables. But couldn't get it. I posted my code below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question mentions '*in a database*', rather than use the information schema, I used the database:

```
select t.name, 
        STUFF ((
            select ',' + c.name
            from TEST_DB.sys.columns c
                join TEST_DB.sys.tables tt on tt.object_id = t.object_id and t.object_id = c.object_id
                join TEST_DB.sys.schemas s on tt.schema_id = s.schema_id
            order by t.name, c.column_id
            for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as columns
from TEST_DB.sys.tables t
            where t.name = 'PutTableNameHere if you want to filter'
```

Leave the where clause out for all tables in a specific database.