# Pass table variable to exec SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, exec

I am trying to write this stored procedure but I have trouble passing result of temp table (or table variable) to `EXEC (@SQL)` task:

```
    DECLARE @colsUnpivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @Table_Name as Varchar(200)
    DECLARE @transaction_Table   NVarchar(500)

    SET @Table_Name = 'opd_scholar'
    SET @transaction_Table = 'opd_scholar_transaction'

    --DECLARE @TEMP TABLE(colsUnpivot varchar(max))
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP (colsUnpivot varchar(max))

    SELECT @colsUnpivot = 'SELECT 
  STUFF ( (
            SELECT '', ''+ QUOTENAME(InTab.COLUMN_NAME)
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS InTab
            WHERE InTab.TABLE_NAME = OutTab.TABLE_NAME
            ORDER BY InTab.ORDINAL_POSITION
            FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE 
            ).value(''.'',''VARCHAR(MAX)''
         ) , 1,1,SPACE(0))
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS OutTab
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '''+ @Table_Name +'''
     GROUP BY OutTab.TABLE_NAME'
   --INSERT INTO @TEMP (colsUnpivot)
   INSERT INTO #TEMP (colsUnpivot)
   EXEC(@colsUnpivot)
   PRINT @colsUnpivot
   --SELECT colsUnpivot FROM @TEMP
   SELECT colsUnpivot FROM #TEMP

   DECLARE @TEMP1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT colsUnpivot FROM #TEMP'

   --PRINT @TEMP

    SET @query 
     = 'INSERT INTO '+ @transaction_Table +' (  unitid,institution,city,state,zip,code_name,lkp_value) 
  SELECT unitid,institution,city,state,zip,code_name,lkp_value
  FROM  
  (
  SELECT unitid,institution,city,state,zip, '+ @TEMP1+'
  FROM '+@Table_name+') AS cp
    UNPIVOT (lkp_value for code_name  IN ('+@TEMP1+')
   ) AS up' 
  PRINT @Query
 --PRINT @Query1
  EXEC(@query)
  DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

I also used table variable (see commented area) but not sure how this works.

Please copy and paste this code into your query window to get more understanding.
Thats right Hogan. I want the result of @colsUnpivot inside some variable so that I can pss that to my next segment of code where currently I am using @TEMP1.

Comment: `but I have trouble passing result of temp table`, can you explain what's your problem?

Comment: Something is strange here, on one hand it looks like you are trying to make a comma separated list of columns.  but you say you want to pass a table variable.  In any case the problem is clearly here -> `DECLARE @TEMP1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT colsUnpivot FROM #TEMP'`  I believe you want @TEMP1 (nice variable name!) to hold the column list not that select string.

Comment: I really don't need to copy and paste into a window to understand.  You have a problem with scope here -- if you have a dynamic SQL to create a variable you can't pass that back -- the only way to do this is with a separate function or find a way to not use dynamic SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @colList VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @colList = 
  Stuff((
    Select ', ' + C.COLUMN_NAME
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS As C
    Where C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        And C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    Order By C.ORDINAL_POSITION
    For Xml Path('')
 ), 1, 2, '') 
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES As T
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @Table_Name
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

and then use `@colList` instead of `@TEMP1`

You don't need a temporary table or any of the other madness.

(nb -- I got the column code from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4936669/215752)

Comment: Thanks but thats not working and thats why I requested to execute it. Here is the error,  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Hogan.

Comment: @nick -- if this answers your questions / helps you, please consider up-voting and marking as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure @Hogan. Just marked this answer as my answer because here u got rid of those complex dynamic sql part and made my life easy.